# Let $A_1A_2....A_n$ be the regular polygon incribed a circle $(O)$ with radius $R$ what is value $k=\frac{\sum_{i<j} A_iA_j^\alpha}{R^\alpha}$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

Let $A_1A_2....A_n$ be the regular polygon incribed a circle $(O)$ with radius $R$,  $\alpha$ is real number, let $$k=\frac{\sum_{i<j} A_iA_j^\alpha}{R^\alpha}$$

> **My question:** I am looking for value of $k=?$

Comment: Your attempt so far?

Comment: Have you tried using complex numbers?

Comment: Is it $\left(\overline{A_iA_j}\right)^\alpha$?

Comment: @SameerBaheti  $A_iA_j$ is distance from $A_i$ to $A_j$

Comment: Is that distance raised to the power of $\alpha$?

Comment: @SameerBaheti Let $\alpha=1$ ?

Comment: And also the polygon is convex?

Comment: @SameerBaheti Regular polygon

Comment: I mean is it a regular convex polygon?

Comment: Yes, regular convex polygon incribed a circle $(O)$ with radius $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $A_1A_2....A_n$ is a regular convex polygon incribed a circle $(O)$ with radius $R$, then find $$k=\frac{\sum_{i<j} A_iA_j^\alpha}{R^\alpha}$$
> , where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Put $\alpha=1$ at the end.

Essentially, $k$ is just the sum of all the sides and diagonals in a regular convex polygon, each raised to the power of some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, divided by $R^\alpha$.

By drawing all the possible lines of some such polygons, you can conclude$^1$ that the ``length types'' in a polygon of side $n$ are as follows:

**CASE I**: $n=2m-1,\ m\in\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Type of line} & \text{Quantity} & \text{Length of line}\\ \hline
\overline{A_1A_{1+l}},\ l=1,2,\ldots,m-1 & n & 2R\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{l\pi}{n}\right)\\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{align*}
k&= \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}\left[n\times 2R\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{l\pi}{n}\right)\right]^\alpha}{R^\alpha}\\
k&=(2n)^\alpha\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}\sin^\alpha\left(\displaystyle\frac{l\pi}{n}\right)\\
\text{For }\alpha=1,\ k&=2n\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{l\pi}{n}\right)\\
k&=n\displaystyle\cot\frac{\pi}{2n}\ \forall\ n=2m-1,\ m\in\mathbb N-\{1\}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Proceed as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552064/sum-k-0n-1-sink-frac-pin-theta) to get equation $(1)$. Nudge me should you face any difficulty simplifying.

**CASE II**: $n=2m,\ m\in\mathbb{N}-\{1\}$

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Type of line} & \text{Quantity} & \text{Length of line} \\ \hline
\overline{A_1A_{1+l}},\ l=1,2,\ldots,m-1 & n & 2R\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{l\pi}{n}\right)\\ \hline
\overline{A_1A_{1+m}} & \frac n2 & 2R\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{m\pi}{n}\right)=2R\\ \hline
\end{array}
Increasing just one side from the previous case adds only a term $(\frac n22R)^\alpha=(nR)^\alpha$ in the numerator as follows:
\begin{align*}
k&= \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{m-1}\left[n\times 2R\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{l\pi}{n}\right)\right]^\alpha+(nR)^\alpha}{R^\alpha}\\
k&=n\displaystyle\cot\frac{\pi}{2n}\ \forall\ n=2m,\ m\in\mathbb N-\{1\}
\end{align*}
by similar procedure.

Finally,
$$\boxed{k|_{\alpha=1}=n\displaystyle\cot\frac{\pi}{2n}\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb N-\{1,2\}}$$

---

$^1$ One can prove it using permutations and combinations.

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than posting complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).