# How to prove that $\tan1^{°}+\tan7^{°}+\dots+\tan175^{°}=-30\sqrt3$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $\tan1^{°}+\tan7^{°}+\dots+\tan175^{°}=-30\sqrt3$?

I noticed that $1^{°},7^{°},\dots,175^{°}$ form an arithmetic.

Comment: Can you post the third term in the sequence? Do you have it with you?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Assuming the angles are in an AP.

Comment: @piteer, Set $\theta=1^\circ,n=30$ to find the sum to be $$-30\cot\left(30\cdot90^\circ+30\cdot1^\circ\right)$$

Now,
$$\cot\left(30\cdot90^\circ+30\cdot1^\circ\right)=\cot\left(15\cdot180^\circ+30^\circ\right)=\cot30^\circ$$

Comment: @piteer, The previous comment actually missed the link : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series