# Prove that $\tan5 \theta = \frac {5\tan \theta -10 \tan ^3 \theta +\tan ^5 \theta} {1-10\tan ^2 \theta +5\tan ^4 \theta}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

As the title suggests, what is required to prove is that
$$\tan5 \theta = \frac {5\tan \theta -10 \tan ^3 \theta +\tan ^5 \theta} {1-10\tan ^2 \theta +5\tan ^4 \theta}$$

I was looking back through my old high school tests and came across this monster and have now -as I did then- no idea where to start with it. This was a test on a 'Complex numbers' unit so using complex numbers is required to prove it (which sadly, I'm quite out of practice on). I'd be really interested to see a solution to problem which has been on the back of my mind ever since I put my eyes on it for the first time. I'm assuming the first step should be to open $\tan 5\theta = \frac {\sin 5\theta} {\cos 5\theta}$ but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Try considering the real and imaginary parts on both sides of De Moivre's formula for $n = 5$: $$\cos 5\theta + i \sin 5\theta =(\cos \theta + i\sin\theta)^5$$ and using Binomial expansion for the right hand side.

Comment: @Malcom, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\cos5x+i\sin5x=\left(\cos x+i\sin x\right)^{5}=$$$$\cos^{5}x-10\cos^{3}x\sin^{2}x+5\cos x\sin^{4}x+i\left(5\cos^{4}x\sin x-10\cos^{2}x\sin^{3}x+\sin^{5}x\right)$$

([De Moivre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula))

Comment: Although equivalent, it's computationally a bit simpler to consider the argument of $(1+i\tan(x))^5$

Answer (score -1):

$$\tan (3\theta + 2\theta)= (\tan 3\theta + \tan 2\theta)/(1-\tan 3\theta  \tan2\theta )$$

Put the value
Just expand the terms and u will get the answer

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please take a look at [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about formatting your answer.  As it stands it is very difficult to read.