# reference for finit sum of cotangents

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, reference-request, summation

Hi I found a finite summation of cotangents as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cot^2(z + \frac{k\pi}{n}) = n^2 - n + n^2 \cot^2(n z), \quad  n > 0$$
in the URL bellow

http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cot/introductions/Cot/ShowAll.html

Can anyone introduce a book or reference which includes the above summation?
I want to see the proof and study more on them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607134/cotangent-summation-proof

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference that you may find useful:

Cvijović, Djurdje. "Summation formulae for finite cotangent sums." Applied Mathematics and Computation 215.3 (2009): 1135-1140.