# Sum of squared cotangent functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Using Mathematica I notice that

$\cot^2(\pi/2)=0$

$\cot^2(\pi/3)+\cot^2(2\pi/3) = 2/3 $

$\cot^2(\pi/4)+\cot^2(2\pi/4)+\cot^2(3\pi/4) = 2$

$\cot^2(\pi/5)+\cot^2(2\pi/5)+\cot^2(3\pi/5)+\cot^2(4\pi/5) = 4$

$\cot^2(\pi/6)+\cot^2(2\pi/6)+\cot^2(3\pi/6)+\cot^2(4\pi/6)+\cot^2(5\pi/6) = 20/3$

It seems that the summation of below series

$\cot^2(\pi/k)+\cot^2(2\pi/k)+\cdots+\cot^2((k-1)\pi/k)$

is an integer when $k$ and $3$ are comprime and $N/3$ when $k$ is multiple of $3$. Why is that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562037/question-regarding-fn-cot2-left-frac-pi-n-right-cot2-left-frac2-pin

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657093/reference-for-finit-sum-of-cotangents