# Find $\sum_{k=0}^6cot({\pi\over 21} + {k\pi\over 7})$

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series

Find $$\sum_{k=0}^6cot({\pi\over 21} + {k\pi\over 7})$$

I don't know how to do this at all. I initially started using complex numbers but couldn't get it.

Please give a simple solution.Thanks.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607134/cotangent-summation-proof?lq=1

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as $\frac{e^{ix}}{sin(x)}-i$ . Now we have $sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2i}$ now can you continue.