# Value of $\tan(1^{\circ})+\tan(2^{\circ})+\tan(3^{\circ})+...+\tan(89^{\circ})$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Is there any method to find value of
$$\tan(1^{\circ})+\tan(2^{\circ})+\tan(3^{\circ})+\dots+\tan(89^{\circ})$$ without using calculator.

To find the same sum for sine and cosine , I used De-Movier's Theorem but here I can't see any approach working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps the tangent addition formula might help? It might take some time to fully calculate everything though.

Comment: @tatan I don't think so. $tan(45)$ alone is 1. In case of product it will be 1

Comment: This is related to [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series), but not the same.

Comment: The answer here is not particularly nice, I think: it's the root near $265.017$ of a polynomial of degree $24$, irreducible over the rationals (and too big to fit in a comment).

Comment: An approximation can be found by considering the sum as a Riemann sum for the integral $\frac{360}{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{360}89}\tan(x){\rm d}x = -\frac{180 \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{180}\right)\right)}{\pi } \approx 231.95$.

Comment: Hint: Find the coefficient of the $x^{88}$ term in the polynomial $$P(x) = (x-\tan 1^{\circ})(x-\tan 2^{\circ})(x-\tan 3^{\circ})\dots(x-\tan 89^{\circ})$$