# Evaluating sum of squares of $\csc(x)$ where angles are in geometric progression

Tags: trigonometry

I have to evaluate the following finite sum:

$$A = \csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right) + \csc^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right) + \csc^2\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)$$

**My work:**

Set $u = e^{i\pi/9}$, thus
$$A = \frac{-4}{(u - 1/u)^2} + \frac{-4}{(u^2 - 1/u^2)^2} + \frac{-4}{(u^4 - 1/u^4)^2}$$
or
$$A = -4\left[\left(\frac{u}{u^2-1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{u^2}{u^4-1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{u^4}{u^8-1}\right)^2\right]$$

I’m unsure how to proceed. Help, preferably proceeding with complex exponents will be appreciated.

EDIT: if the value of $\csc^2(\pi/3)$ is know, one can reduce the problem to:
$$2A + 2\csc^2(\pi/3) = \frac{80}{3}$$
Using $$\sum_{r=1}^{m-1} \csc^2(\frac{r\pi}{m}) = \frac{m^2-1}{3}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate: $\csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right)+\csc^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)+\csc^2\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749306/evaluate-csc2-left-frac-pi9-right-csc2-left-frac2-pi9-right-c) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Ccsc%5E2%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D%5Cright)%2B%5Ccsc%5E2%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D%5Cright)%2B%5Ccsc%5E2%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B4%5Cpi%7D%7B9%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1).

Comment: That does answer it but not the solution I’m looking for. I guess I’ll work with that. Thank you anyway