# Deriving multi-angle addition sin formulaes

Tags: trigonometry

There is no derivation I could find anywhere, and is rarely discussed online.

$\sin(A+B+C+\ldots)$ is what is referred as multi-angle sum not $\sin(3x)$ or $\sin(8x)$, as its finite.

$\sin(\theta_1​+\theta_2​+\theta_3​+\ldots)=\cos(\theta_1​)\cos(\theta_2)\cos(\theta_3​)\cdots(s_1-s_3+s_5-s_7+\ldots)$

where

$s_n​=\sum_{\rm cyc}\tan(\theta_1)\tan(\theta_2)\tan(\theta_3)\cdots\tan(\theta_n)$.

https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/

Comment: Are you asking for what the expression is, or for a derivation of it? Is there a context where you want to apply it?

Comment: Use the two-angle sum case and induction (since, for example $\sin (A+B+C) = \sin ((A+B)+C) $)

Comment: @ConMan derivation without induction

Comment: @Jon  i prefer no induction

Comment: In fact, what you mention can be more or less "recasted" as a  formula for $\tan(\sum \theta_i)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2171738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea is to use Euler's formula for one angle
$$  e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=
\cos(\theta)(1+i\tan(\theta)). \tag{1} $$
Thus, for several angles let $\,\theta:=\theta_1+\theta_2+\dots+\theta_n.\,$
Then let $$ E:=e^{i\theta_1} e^{i\theta_2}\cdots e^{i\theta_n}=
e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta). \tag{2}$$
From equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ get
$$ E \!=\! \cos(\theta_1)\!\cos(\theta_2)\cdots\cos(\theta_n)
(1\!+\!i\tan(\theta_1))(1\!+\!i\tan(\theta_2))\cdots(1\!+\!i\tan(\theta_n))
. \tag{3}$$
Expand equation $(3)$ and separate the real and imaginary parts to get
$$ \cos(\theta) = \cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\cdots\cos(\theta_n)
(e_0-e_2+e_4-\dots) \tag{4} $$ and
$$ \sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\cdots\cos(\theta_n)
(e_1-e_3+e_5-\dots) \tag{5} $$
where the $\,e_n\,$ are the $n$-th [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)
of the tangents.

Answer (score 1):

Not a formal answer, but something to consider ...

---

Compare these *trigonographs* for the angle-sum formulas involving two and three angles:

[image]

[image]

It may not be difficult to convince yourself that, for an arbitrary number of angles, the horizontal sides of the diagram (which combine to make the cosine of the total angle) are labeled with all (and only) those products involving an even number of sines of individual angles. Likewise, the vertical sides (for the sine of the total angle) are labeled with products involving an odd number of sines.

That the groupings should be alternately added and subtracted may not be immediately obvious (especially after just two cases), but this might also not take *too* much convincing.

Comment: wonderful, n how did you draw that crispy diagram?

Comment: @Minikute: I use [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org) for my diagrams.

Comment: have u also tried algebraically the derivation, is there a book someone said hobb's trigonometry, but i dont have that book.

Comment: @Minikute: I'd be inclined to use induction for an algebraic derivation, but you've commented that you aren't interested in that. (Of course, even this diagrammatic justification requires some inductive thinking.) Maybe a nice identity comes into play when expanding things in terms of complex exponentials; I haven't given that any thought (but it would likely involve induction, anyway). ... I'm afraid I don't have any book recommendations to offer.