What's the formula for $\tan(\theta_1+\theta_2+\cdots+\theta_n)$? Not in the S1,S2,S3... Format,the formula contains pie notation,what to do with it?
What's the formula for $\tan(\theta_1+\theta_2+\cdots+\theta_n)$?
I searched it up in ChatGPT but got this:
$$ \
\tan(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \cdots + \theta_n) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \tan(\theta_i) - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \tan(\theta_i) \tan(\theta_j) + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} \prod_{i=1}^n \tan(\theta_i)}{1 - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \tan(\theta_i) \tan(\theta_j)}
\] $$
It gave different different answers in many times , I wanna be sure about a real formula...for an important purpose...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See online. Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

This question is similar to: Formula I don't understand in a textbook by L. Harwood Clarke: $\tan (A+B+C + \cdots) = \frac {s_1 - s_3 + s_5 - \cdots} {1 - s_2 + s_4 - \cdots}$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also here.

I'd add that each time you ask the same thing to ChatGPT, it will most likely answer something different since it's only doing some predictions. Best is to search something like this on Google. Now as for the formula you're asking, here is a potential clue for you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171738/proving-tan-theta-1-theta-2-cdots-theta-n-has-the-form-fracs-1-s-3s

@seboll13 , yeah it gave me different different formulas, so I came here to find the right one
