# Expansion of $\tan(nx)$ in powers of $\tan(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\tan(nx)$ is expanded in powers of $\tan(x)$ then what are the constant term and coefficient of $\tan(x)$ in the expansion?

**My try** *I tried solving by comparing with the general formula for $\tan(nx)$ which is given in terms of $\tan(x)$ , $\tan^n(x)$ but did not get the correct answer.*

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/16/04/02/)?

Answer (score 2):

For real $x$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, we have

$$\cos(nx)(1 + i \tan(nx)) = e^{inx} = (e^{ix})^n = (\cos(x)(1 + i\tan(x))^n$$
Compare real and imaginary parts on both side, we have

$$
\tan(nx) 
= \frac{\Im\rm(LHS)}{\Re\rm(LHS)}
=\frac{\Im\rm(RHS)}{\Re\rm(RHS)}
= \frac{\Im\left((1+i\tan x)^n\right)}{\Re\left((1+i\tan x)^n\right)}
$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}\tan(nx) &= \frac{
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n}{2k+1}\tan(x)^{2k+1}
}{
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} (-1)^k\binom{n}{2k} \tan(x)^{2k}
}
= \frac{n \tan(x) + O(\tan(x)^3)}{1 + O(\tan(x)^2)}\\
&= 0 + n\tan(x) + O(\tan(x)^3)
\end{align}
$$
So the constant term is $0$ and the coefficient in front of $\tan(x)$ is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $t = \tan(x)$, then you're expanding $\tan(n \arctan(t))$ in a Taylor series about $t=0$.  Since $\arctan(t) = t + O(t^3)$ and $\tan(x) = x + O(t^3)$, we get
$$ \tan(n \arctan(t)) = n t + O(t^3)$$

BTW, the next term is $$ \frac{n^3-n}{3} t^3$$

Comment: That's a lot like how my book explained it. Since I have no idea what a Taylor series is, I'd love to have a broader explanation to your approach here, thanks.

Comment: [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)