# tan nx is not as popular as Chebyshev polyomials?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, approximation-theory

I noticed that $\tan(nx)$ can be written as the ratio $P(\tan x) / Q(\tan x)$,
where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials.

Indeed, I found a short proof here
[Expansion of $\tan(nx)$ in powers of $\tan(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390489/expansion-of-tannx-in-powers-of-tanx)

What else can we say? If we do the same idea for $\cos(nx)$ we get the Chebyshev polyomials, and we know many things for those.

a ) So I was wondering if $P(X)/Q(X)$ satisfies any extremality properties, like the Chebyshev polyomials?

b)Or are they useful in Pade approximation? Just guessing.

c)Or they can be gained as a solution of differential equations? with coefficients
gotten by recursion relations?

I reached the Chebyshev polyomials in my progress but I am now stuck.

Comment: Just a thought (and not a justifiable answer hence why only a comment) but if you consider expansions of functions using Chebyshev polynomials, the derivatives are generally simpler than if you used $\tan(nx)$, For example, $\cos(nx)$ and $\sin(nx)$ just interchange under differentiation, up to constants, whereas expressions containing linear combinations of $\tan(nx)$ involve $\sec^2(nx)$. Basically, why choose a basis that creates complexity with no other obvious benefit?

Comment: Since your talking about $P(x)/Q(x)$ instead of $P(\tan x)/Q(\tan x)$ in part a, that is taking solutions $x_0$ of $x=\tan x$. $\tan n x_0 = \frac{P(x_0)}{Q(x_0)}$