# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{44} \tan(4k+1)^\circ = 45$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want a way to solve this series without resorting to the ugly expansion of $\tan nx$. Can anyone help? (the angles are in degrees)

Show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{44}\tan(4k+1)^\circ = 45$$

Comment: Your title does not match the question's body.

Comment: My bad, I will fix it :)

Comment: A reference to this can be found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t207f6h534227_sum_of_tangents)

Comment: @lulu, thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, we should have a simple solution for this problem.

Comment: @xpaul, Not sure if the answer linked here is too complex! Just put $$\theta=1^\circ, n=45$$