# Show that $\tan(A_1+A_2+....A_n) = \frac{s_1-s_3+s_5+...}{1-s_2+s_4-s_6+....}$

Tags: trigonometry

Where $s_r$ = sum of product of tangents of angles $A_1,A_2...A_n$ taken $r$ at a time.I am expected to prove by induction. How do we use induction in a situation like this?

Comment: Assume the formula holds for $\tan(A_1+\cdots+A_{n-1})$ and use the addition formula for $\tan$ to deduce it for $\tan(A_1+\cdots+A_{n})$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series

Comment: I have come to this stage.$\frac{s_1..s_{n-1}+tanA_n+tanA_n(-s_2+s_4....s_{n-1}}{1-s_2+s_4...s_{n-2} - tan A_n(s_1-s_3...s_{n-1}}$